# PHP fopen($file, "w") permission denied

Tags: php, apache, fopen, raspbian, permission-denied

I have a problem with a php script on my webserver (Apache/2.4.10 on Raspbian), I can't generate a new file on it. I have tried chmod 777 (which is really bad practice) and it still didn't work. I have been struggling with this for a few days and even after extensive research I couldn't find a solution to this problem. Below is my code and the error messages generated by it:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$newwish = fopen("newfile.txt", "w+");
$txt = "LALALA";
fwrite($newwish, $txt);
fclose($newwish);
?>
```

> Warning: fopen(newfile.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
>   in /var/www/html/handlers/wish.php on line 4
>
> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /var/www/html/handlers/wish.php on line 6
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /var/www/html/handlers/wish.php on line 7

Comment: What have you chmodded?

Comment: @Chris apache's www folder, recursively, after I made sure that it is owned by the user under which apache is running

Comment: That seems like overkill. If you do `ls -la` in the folder your PHP file is in what output do you get?

Comment: total 16
    drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi   4096 Apr 28 21:31 .
    drwxrwxr-x 7 pi root 4096 Apr 28 21:31 ..
    -rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi     61 Apr 28 22:11 search.php
    -rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi    163 Apr 28 22:11 wish.php

Comment: It doesn't look like it's chmodded to 777 then.

Comment: What command are you running to chmod it?

Comment: From the same directory, can you try `chmod 777 .` and see if that works?

Comment: @Chris You were right, I didn't chmod it correctly, now it works, but what security risks does 777ing a file that is available to the internet introduce?

Comment: Provided you only `chmod` what you need, the risk is very low. It would still be more secure to `chown` the group to `www-data` and set the directory permissions to 775.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @Vic The error I encountered was a denial of permission wheras the question you mentioned is about php not finding a directory

Comment: @boban, the answers to the question I pointed to includes problems of permissions and how to solve them

Answer (score -2):

I tried your script in the CLI and works well.

Try to make www-data the owner of the folder and the content that contain the script:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data phpscript/
```

and then give to the php script file permissions:

```
chmod 644 index.php
```